Content Security Policy not blocking the loading of third party javascript
I am trying to implement Content Security Policy a new website. I can see that the following HTTP header is set in the network tab of Chrome.
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https:

However, javscript and css from third party websites are still loading without any errors.
Is there anything additional I need to add in order to get third-party libraries blocked?

Your policy allows anything from 'self' which is the same host, but also anything from https:, which means anything served over https. Remove https:, and preferably insert the necessary sources in more specific directives such as script-src, style-src etc.

The default-src directive applies to all resources. Instead of that use script-src to specify exactly what scripts are allowed to load.
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://www.acme.com;

This allows scripts from your own domain and from https://www.acme.com
